# Signal 6 occuring on device during shutdown of node

Tags: redhawksdr

I have a node with a GPP device and PICOFLEXOR_1 device. I can shut down both devices successfully if I do not start a waveform that uses the PICOFLEXOR_1. However, if I start a waveform, release the waveform and then shutdown the node I get a signal 6 on the PICOFLEXOR device. It appears there is no deviceIOR for the PICOFLEXOR_1 device. Below is the trace from the good shutdown and the bad shutdown.

#

Here is a good shutdown of the node, a waveform was not allocated

root@atlas-i-z7e:~# INFO:DeviceManager_impl - shutting down DeviceManager
TRACE:DeviceManager_impl - unregistering DeviceManager
TRACE:DeviceManager_impl - Releasing device GPP_1
TRACE:DeviceManager_impl - Comparing tmpDeviceIOR to deviceIOR IOR:0100000025000
00049444c3a43462f41676772656761746545786563757461626c654465766963653a312e3000000
000010000000000000064000000010102000d0000003137322e32322e32342e383800009e950e000
000fed2a3c754000005a900000000000000020000000000000008000000010000000054544101000
0001c00000001000000010001000100000001000105090101000100000009010100 IOR:01000000
2500000049444c3a43462f41676772656761746545786563757461626c654465766963653a312e30
00000000010000000000000064000000010102000d0000003137322e32322e32342e383800009e95
0e000000fed2a3c754000005a9000000000000000200000000000000080000000100000000545441
010000001c00000001000000010001000100000001000105090101000100000009010100
TRACE:DeviceManager_impl - Matched device IOR
TRACE:DeviceManager_impl - Not unregistering device GPP_1 from domain manager be
cause we are shutting down
TRACE:DeviceManager_impl - Releasing device PICOFLEXOR_1
TRACE:DeviceManager_impl - Comparing tmpDeviceIOR to deviceIOR IOR:0100000012000
00049444c3a43462f4465766963653a312e30000000010000000000000064000000010102000d000
0003137322e32322e32342e3838000085a80e000000fed8a3c754000005bd0000000004000002000
00000000000080000000100000000545441010000001c00000001000000010001000100000001000
105090101000100000009010100 IOR:010000001200000049444c3a43462f4465766963653a312e
30000000010000000000000064000000010102000d0000003137322e32322e32342e3838000085a8
0e000000fed8a3c754000005bd000000000400000200000000000000080000000100000000545441
010000001c00000001000000010001000100000001000105090101000100000009010100
TRACE:DeviceManager_impl - Matched device IOR
TRACE:DeviceManager_impl - Not unregistering device PICOFLEXOR_1 from domain man
ager because we are shutting down
TRACE:DeviceManager_impl - Sending SIGTERM to device process 0x5a9
TRACE:DeviceManager_impl - Sending SIGTERM to device process 0x5bd
INFO:DeviceManager_impl - Child process GPP_1 (pid 0x5a9) has exited with status
 0
TRACE:DeviceManager_impl - Sending SIGTERM to device process 0x5bd
TRACE:DeviceManager_impl - Sending SIGKILL to device process 0x5bd
TRACE:DeviceManager_impl - Unbinding device manager context
TRACE:DeviceManager_impl - Unregistering file systems
TRACE:DeviceManager_impl - Deleting file systems
TRACE:DeviceManager_impl - Deleted file systems
INFO:DeviceManager_impl - done shutting down DeviceManager
TRACE:DeviceManager_impl - shutting down ORB
WARN:DeviceManager_impl - Child process PICOFLEXOR_1 (pid 0x5bd) has terminated
with signal 0x9
INFO:DeviceManager - Goodbye!
DEBUG:DeviceManager - Farewell!

[1]+  Done                    nodeBooter -debug 5 -d /var/redhawk/sdr/dev/nodes/
PICOFLEXOR/DeviceManager.dcd.xml
root@atlas-i-z7e:~#
root@atlas-i-z7e:~#
root@atlas-i-z7e:~# #########################
root@atlas-i-z7e:~#root@atlas-i-z7e:~#

#

#### now shutdown after waveform allocated

root@atlas-i-z7e:~# TRACE:PropertySet_impl - Query all properties
TRACE:PropertySet_impl - Query returning 2 properties
TRACE:PropertySet_impl - Query all properties
TRACE:PropertySet_impl - Query returning 2 properties
INFO:DeviceManager_impl - shutting down DeviceManager
TRACE:DeviceManager_impl - unregistering DeviceManager
TRACE:DeviceManager_impl - Releasing device GPP_1
TRACE:DeviceManager_impl - Comparing tmpDeviceIOR to deviceIOR IOR:0100000025000
00049444c3a43462f41676772656761746545786563757461626c654465766963653a312e3000000
000010000000000000064000000010102000d0000003137322e32322e32342e383800003cea0e000
000fefcaac754000005e600000000000000020000000000000008000000010000000054544101000
0001c00000001000000010001000100000001000105090101000100000009010100 IOR:01000000
2500000049444c3a43462f41676772656761746545786563757461626c654465766963653a312e30
00000000010000000000000064000000010102000d0000003137322e32322e32342e383800003cea
0e000000fefcaac754000005e6000000000000000200000000000000080000000100000000545441
010000001c00000001000000010001000100000001000105090101000100000009010100
TRACE:DeviceManager_impl - Matched device IOR
TRACE:DeviceManager_impl - Not unregistering device GPP_1 from domain manager be
cause we are shutting down
**TRACE:DeviceManager_impl - Releasing device PICOFLEXOR_1**
 glibc detected  **/var/redhawk/sdr/dev/devices/PICOFLEXOR/cpp/PICOFLEXOR: d
ouble free or corruption (out): 0x000b23e0 ***
ERROR:DeviceManager_impl - CORBA COMM_FAILURE exception calling releaseObject on
 PICOFLEXOR_1
TRACE:DeviceManager_impl - Sending SIGTERM to device process 1510
TRACE:DeviceManager_impl - Sending SIGTERM to device process 1529
WARN:DeviceManager_impl - Child process PICOFLEXOR_1 (pid 1529) has terminated w
ith signal 6**
INFO:DeviceManager_impl - Child process GPP_1 (pid 1510) has exited with status
0
TRACE:DeviceManager_impl - Unbinding device manager context
TRACE:DeviceManager_impl - Unregistering file systems
TRACE:DeviceManager_impl - Deleting file systems
TRACE:DeviceManager_impl - Deleted file systems
INFO:DeviceManager_impl - done shutting down DeviceManager
TRACE:DeviceManager_impl - shutting down ORB
INFO:DeviceManager - Goodbye!
DEBUG:DeviceManager - Farewell!

Answer (score 0):

How are you launching the waveform?  Looks like you are running nodebooter as root.  Have you tried running nodebooter as a regular user or as a redhawk user?